# Django .annotate with When

Tags: django, database

I am trying to do a query and get a sum of values based on a condition.

I need all the **'shares'** when the **'action' == '+'**

I have to group by the issues.

```
 qs = Trades.objects.all ().filter ( id = id ) 
    .annotate (
        d_shrs = Sum ( When (
           action = '+', then = 'shares'
        ) )
  ).order_by ( 'issue' )
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Case (it allows you to use if-else kind of constructs in your queries) with a When, F will get you the actual value of the field

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, F, Sum

qs = Trades.objects.filter(id=id).annotate(
        d_shrs=Sum(
            Case(
                When (
                    action='+', then=F('shares')
                )
            )
        )
    ).order_by('issue')
```

Comment: Thanks, got it to work but decided that Pandas was a far better way to do the calculations I needed for this.  Not sure which is more efficient though? Cheers.

Comment: I have very limited experience with Pandas (essentially just putting data into an excel, didn't do any computations). But the annotate on django has worked pretty well for me for complex calculations on medium amount of data in the tables (roughly 100k rows)